# jQuery .bind is being executed more than once?

Tags: jquery, html

**Original code:** (can be seen working here: http://sandbox.hokuten.net/jqrpg/)

```
/* google.setOnLoadCallback(function() { */
$(function() {

jqr = new Object();
jqr.settings = new Object();
jqr.settings.sprite_width = 16;
jqr.settings.sprite_height = 16;
jqr.settings.space = false;

jqr.p = new Object();
function jqrpgResetPlayer() {
    jqr.p.face = 'd';
    jqr.p.x = 3;
    jqr.p.y = 3;
    jqr.p.state = 'map';
}

jqr.map = new Object();
jqr.map.height  = 16;
jqr.map.width   = 16;
jqr.map.terrain = [
 '01','02','03','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11',
 '01','01','00','00','11','00','00','11','11','00','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '01','00','00','00','11','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '01','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','11','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '01','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','11','11','11','11','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','11','11','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','11','01','01','01',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','11','11','00','00','00','01',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00',
];
jqr.map.terrain_walkable = [
 '00','01','02',
];

jqr.battle = new Object();

jqrpgBuildMapHtml();
jqrpgUpdateMapClasses();
jqrpgResetPlayer();
jqrpgSetPlayerFace(jqr.p.face);
jqrpgSetPlayer(jqr.p.x, jqr.p.y);
jqrpgBindKeys();

/**
 * only call this once
 */
function jqrpgBuildInterface() {
    $('#jqrpg_wrapper').width($('#jqrpg_screen').width());
}
function jqrpgBuildMapHtml() {
    $('#jqrpg_screen, #jqrpg_wrapper').height(jqr.map.height * jqr.settings.sprite_height)
     .width(jqr.map.width * jqr.settings.sprite_width);
    m = $('#jqrpg_map');
    m.empty();
    for (y = 0; y < jqr.map.height; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < jqr.map.width; x++) {
            // cti = y * x; // current_tile_index
            // <![CDATA[
            m.append('<span>.</span>');
            // ]]>
        }
    }
}

/**
 * call this whenever enter a new screen
 */
function jqrpgUpdateMapClasses() {
    for (y = 0; y < jqr.map.height; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < jqr.map.width; x++) {
            cti = y * jqr.map.height + x; // current_tile_index
            ct = $('#jqrpg_map span').eq(cti);
            ct.removeClass()
             .addClass('tile')
             .addClass('tile_x' + x + 'y'+ y)
             .addClass('tile_' + jqr.map.terrain[cti]);
            if (y && x == 0) ct.addClass('tile_row');
        }
    }
    $('#jqrpg_map').fadeIn('slow');
}
function jqrpgSetPlayerFace(new_face) {
    $('#jqrpg_player').removeClass().addClass('face_' + new_face);
}
function jqrpgSetPlayer(new_x, new_y) {
    $('#jqrpg_player').css({
     'left' : new_x * jqr.settings.sprite_width,
     'top' : new_y * jqr.settings.sprite_height
    });
}

/**
 * key binding
 */
function jqrpgBindKeys() {
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'up', function() {
        if (jqr.p.state != 'map') return false;
        jqrpgSetPlayerFace('u');
        return jqrpgMovePlayer(0, -1);
    })
    .bind('keydown', 'Down', function() {
        if (jqr.p.state != 'map') return false;
        jqrpgSetPlayerFace('d');
        return jqrpgMovePlayer(0, 1);
    })
    .bind('keydown', 'Left', function() {
        if (jqr.p.state != 'map') return false;
        jqrpgSetPlayerFace('l');
        return jqrpgMovePlayer(-1, 0);
    })
    .bind('keydown', 'Right', function() {
        if (jqr.p.state != 'map') return false;
        jqrpgSetPlayerFace('r');
        return jqrpgMovePlayer(1, 0);
    })
    .bind('keypress', 'Space', function() {
        // if (console) console.log('space');
        if (jqr.p.state == 'map') return false;
        jqr.settings.space = true;
        if (jqr.p.state == 'battle') jqrpgBattle();
        return true;
    });
}

/**
 * movement
 */
function jqrpgMovePlayer(new_x, new_y) {
    // if (console) console.log('x: ' + jqr.p.x + '  y: ' + jqr.p.y);
    if (jqr.p.x + new_x + 1 > jqr.map.width
     || jqr.p.y + new_y + 1 > jqr.map.height
     || jqr.p.x + new_x + 1 == 0
     || jqr.p.y + new_y + 1 == 0
     || !jqrpgIsTileWalkable(jqr.p.x + new_x, jqr.p.y + new_y)
    ) return;
    jqr.p.x += new_x;   jqr.p.y += new_y;

    $('#jqrpg_player').dequeue().animate({
     left: jqr.p.x * jqr.settings.sprite_width,
     top: jqr.p.y * jqr.settings.sprite_height
    },
    250,
    function() {
        jqrpgGetRandomBattle();
    });
    return true;
}
function jqrpgIsTileWalkable(x, y) {
    return jQuery.inArray(jqr.map.terrain[(y) * 16 + x], jqr.map.terrain_walkable) > -1;
}
/**
 * battle
 */
function jqrpgGetRandomBattle() {
    var likelihood = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    if (likelihood == 1) {
        jqrpgBattleInit();
    }
}
function jqrpgBattleInit() {
    jqr.p.state = 'battle';
    m = $('#jqrpg_menu');
    m.show();
    // <![CDATA[
    m.html('<p>Random battle! Press [space] to continue.</p>');
    // ]]>
    $('#jqrpg_wrapper').css({'border-color' : '#a00'});
}
function jqrpgBattle() {
    if (jqr.settings.space) {
        jqr.settings.space = false;
        jqrpgBattleEnd();
    }
}
function jqrpgBattleEnd() {
    jqr.p.state = 'map';
    $('#jqrpg_wrapper').css({'border-color' : '#000'});
    m.fadeOut('fast');
}

});
```

**My code:** (Can be seen working here: http://project-vanquish.co.cc/jQRPG/)

```
$(function() {

jqr = new Object();
jqr.settings = new Object();
jqr.settings.sprite_width = 16;
jqr.settings.sprite_height = 16;
jqr.settings.space = false;

jqr.p = new Object();
function jqrpgResetPlayer() {
    jqr.p.face = 'd';
    jqr.p.x = 3;
    jqr.p.y = 3;
    jqr.p.state = 'map';
}

jqr.map = new Object();
jqr.map.height  = 16;
jqr.map.width   = 16;
jqr.map.terrain = [
 '01','02','03','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11','11',
 '01','01','00','00','11','00','00','11','11','00','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '01','00','00','00','11','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '01','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','11','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '01','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','11','11','11','11','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','11','11','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','00','00','11','01','01','01',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','11','11','11','00','00','00','01',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00',
 '00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00','00',
];
jqr.map.terrain_walkable = [
 '00','01','02',
];

jqr.battle = new Object();

jqrpgBuildMapHtml();
jqrpgUpdateMapClasses();
jqrpgResetPlayer();
jqrpgSetPlayerFace(jqr.p.face);
jqrpgSetPlayer(jqr.p.x, jqr.p.y);
jqrpgBindKeys();

/**
 * only call this once
 */
function jqrpgBuildInterface() {
    $('#jqrpg_wrapper').width($('#jqrpg_screen').width());
}
function jqrpgBuildMapHtml() {
    $('#jqrpg_screen, #jqrpg_wrapper').height(jqr.map.height * jqr.settings.sprite_height)
     .width(jqr.map.width * jqr.settings.sprite_width);
    m = $('#jqrpg_map');
    m.empty();
    for (y = 0; y < jqr.map.height; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < jqr.map.width; x++) {
            // cti = y * x; // current_tile_index
            // <![CDATA[
            m.append('<span>.</span>');
            // ]]>
        }
    }
}

/**
 * call this whenever enter a new screen
 */
function jqrpgUpdateMapClasses() {
    for (y = 0; y < jqr.map.height; y++) {
        for (x = 0; x < jqr.map.width; x++) {
            cti = y * jqr.map.height + x; // current_tile_index
            ct = $('#jqrpg_map span').eq(cti);
            ct.removeClass()
             .addClass('tile')
             .addClass('tile_x' + x + 'y'+ y)
             .addClass('tile_' + jqr.map.terrain[cti]);
            if (y && x == 0) ct.addClass('tile_row');
        }
    }
    $('#jqrpg_map').fadeIn('slow');
}
function jqrpgSetPlayerFace(new_face) {
    $('#jqrpg_player').removeClass().addClass('face_' + new_face);
}
function jqrpgSetPlayer(new_x, new_y) {
    $('#jqrpg_player').css({
     'left' : new_x * jqr.settings.sprite_width,
     'top' : new_y * jqr.settings.sprite_height
    });
}

/**
 * key binding
 */
function jqrpgBindKeys() {
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'up', function() {
        if (jqr.p.state != 'map') return false;
        jqrpgSetPlayerFace('u');
        return jqrpgMovePlayer(0, -1);
    })
    .bind('keydown', 'Down', function() {
        if (jqr.p.state != 'map') return false;
        jqrpgSetPlayerFace('d');
        return jqrpgMovePlayer(0, 1);
    })
    .bind('keydown', 'Left', function() {
        if (jqr.p.state != 'map') return false;
        jqrpgSetPlayerFace('l');
        return jqrpgMovePlayer(-1, 0);
    })
    .bind('keydown', 'Right', function() {
        if (jqr.p.state != 'map') return false;
        jqrpgSetPlayerFace('r');
        return jqrpgMovePlayer(1, 0);
    })
    .bind('keypress', 'Space', function() {
        // if (console) console.log('space');
        if (jqr.p.state == 'map') return false;
        jqr.settings.space = true;
        if (jqr.p.state == 'battle') jqrpgBattle();
        return true;
    });
}

/**
 * movement
 */
function jqrpgMovePlayer(new_x, new_y) {
    // if (console) console.log('x: ' + jqr.p.x + '  y: ' + jqr.p.y);
    if (jqr.p.x + new_x + 1 > jqr.map.width
     || jqr.p.y + new_y + 1 > jqr.map.height
     || jqr.p.x + new_x + 1 == 0
     || jqr.p.y + new_y + 1 == 0
     || !jqrpgIsTileWalkable(jqr.p.x + new_x, jqr.p.y + new_y)
    ) return;
    jqr.p.x += new_x;   jqr.p.y += new_y;

    $('#jqrpg_player').dequeue().animate({
     left: jqr.p.x * jqr.settings.sprite_width,
     top: jqr.p.y * jqr.settings.sprite_height
    },
    250,
    function() {
        jqrpgGetRandomBattle();
    });
    return true;
}
function jqrpgIsTileWalkable(x, y) {
    return jQuery.inArray(jqr.map.terrain[(y) * 16 + x], jqr.map.terrain_walkable) > -1;
}
/**
 * battle
 */
function jqrpgGetRandomBattle() {
    var likelihood = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    if (likelihood == 1) {
        jqrpgBattleInit();
    }
}
function jqrpgBattleInit() {
    jqr.p.state = 'battle';
    m = $('#jqrpg_menu');
    m.show();
    // <![CDATA[
    m.html('<p>Random battle! Press [space] to continue.</p>');
    // ]]>
    $('#jqrpg_wrapper').css({'border-color' : '#a00'});
}
function jqrpgBattle() {
    if (jqr.settings.space) {
        jqr.settings.space = false;
        jqrpgBattleEnd();
    }
}
function jqrpgBattleEnd() {
    jqr.p.state = 'map';
    $('#jqrpg_wrapper').css({'border-color' : '#000'});
    m.fadeOut('fast');
}

});
```

***So, the problem I have is that my player movement executes more than once (seems to be 3 times).***

Comment: You aren't showing where `jqrpgBindKeys` is being called from, this is a very important detail :)

Comment: @Neurofluxation - Which browser is giving you trouble? It executes once in Chrome/IE/FF.

Comment: @nick - The code executes perfectly, but instead of a "one square" movement i get a "three square" movement. It happens in all browsers. (Im using IE8, Chrome 5.0.3 and Firefox 3.6.6)

Comment: Please bear in mind that the "original code" hosting on sandbox.hokuten.net works flawlessly - yet I copied EXACTLY that code to my local machine and it doesn't work. Even if I upload it to my host!

Comment: @Neurofluxation - If you're not showing me the problem code I can't help...not sure what to say there. You're not showing where it's called (in the problem version), and the example you posted works flawlessly.  You need to compare what's different from what you're showing me.

Comment: That's just it though - there is no difference - ill paste my code the demo code together for you... you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Neurofluxation - Your page has analytics code, most importantly it's *after* the `</html>`, it should be at the end of the `<body>`...this is going to cause all sorts of weird behavior.  Try removing it.

Comment: @nick - Ok, removed the Analytics code - still the same issue. Have uploaded to: http://www.project-vanquish.co.cc/jQRPG/

Comment: @Neurofluxation - Still on the page here, sure there were no issues uploading?

Comment: @nick (again) - The http://sandbox.hokuten.net/jqrpg/ site is *not* my code. There is no Analytics in my HTML page at all. I TAKE THAT BACK, my free webhost is adding it in...

Comment: @Neurofluxation - Yup, that's causing your issue I'd bet good money...stuff after `</html>` really screws with `document.ready()`.

Comment: ok, cheers - bloody free web hosts! - quickly knock up an answer and ill give you the "rep"

Comment: I have a similar situation with .live('click', ''' ) firing twice for the same single click, but only on an iPad - only fires once everywhere else.  Its not an accidental double click, as it always happens.

Comment: I would narrow down your problems to programming for the iPad ;) - I have no idea I'm afraid @moo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in how they're doing the bindings, with the 1.4.2 event model re-write that approach just doesn't work anymore, but you can write it to work with 1.4.2, like this:

```
function jqrpgBindKeys() {
    $(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
        if (jqr.p.state != 'map' && e.which != 32) return false;
        switch(e.which) {
          case 38: //up
            jqrpgSetPlayerFace('u');
            return jqrpgMovePlayer(0, -1);
          case 40: //down
            jqrpgSetPlayerFace('d');
            return jqrpgMovePlayer(0, 1);
          case 37: //left
            jqrpgSetPlayerFace('l');
            return jqrpgMovePlayer(-1, 0);
          case 39: //right
            jqrpgSetPlayerFace('r');
            return jqrpgMovePlayer(1, 0);
          case 32: //space bar
            if (jqr.p.state == 'map') return false;
            jqr.settings.space = true;
            if (jqr.p.state == 'battle') jqrpgBattle();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

[You can give it a try (using jQuery 1.4.2) here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/kkWM6/). You could also do this via an object map, etc...but this is the quick change version to make it work with 1.4.2.

---

*Separate issue:*
The problem is in your webhost, well...screwing with your page.  If you look at the source on http://www.project-vanquish.co.cc/jQRPG/ you'll see this at the end (modified to remove real domains):

```
</body> 
</html> 
<!-- www.removedToProtectTheGuilty.com Analytics Code --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://analytics.example.com/count.php"></script> 
<noscript><a href="http://www.example.com/"><img src="http://analytics.example.com/count.php" alt="web hosting" /></a></noscript> 
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

That script executing after `</html>` causes all sorts of craziness around `document.ready` and will just give problems in general...if at all possible get rid of it, or try and get it inside `<body></body>`.  Some webhosts look for a tag to stick it in, e.g.:

```
 <div id="analyticsCodeHere"></div>
```

I'd see if you have that option :)

Comment: Perfect, cheers Nick. Even if it wasn't the news I wanted to hear.

Comment: This same issue happens if I use jQuery 1.4.2 as well, I had to degrade to 1.4.1 to get the functionality correct ;)

Comment: @Neurofluxation - You're right, I looked through the 1.4.2 commits and the way they were doing keycodes just breaks with the 1.4.2 event model re-write.  Check the updated answer, I included how to make it more check correctly...this will have no issues in 1.4.2.